# Where are the answer and on_answer methods of the nagare ColorChooser class defined?

Tags: python, web-applications

In the Logic Composition section of the [Nagare component model documentation](http://www.nagare.org/trac/wiki/ComponentModel) reference is made to two methods of the `ColorChooser` component - `answer()` and `on_answer()` but no definition or documentation of them is given.

I would appreciate some reference to what these methods refer to.

Comment: by the way, I would like to be able to tag this question with "nagare" if possible.

Comment: It looks like `answer` is like a signal and `on_answer` is a slot. I've never heard of this framework before, so it could be just a lack of documentation.

Comment: @Blender I agree - and since you've been so kind to create the tag, I think it'd be nice for the OP to have a go at a tag wiki entry http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/86183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Nagare components have those methods, see the [class `component.Component()` documentation](http://www.nagare.org/trac/api/component.py).

This was referred to in the first sentence of the Component Model chapter:

> A component is an object, instance of the `Component` class in [`component.py#component.Component`](http://www.nagare.org/trac/api/component.py#component.Component).